# 1,000-strong battalion - meaning of "strong"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, idiomatic-language

Source: http://rt.com/news/183864-ukraine-european-volunteers-fighting/

> Aleksey Mozgovoy, the commander of ‘Prizrak’ (Ghost) brigade from the Lugansk Region said in an interview to the MK.ru news outlet that in his **1,000-strong** battalion there are fighters from Bulgaria, Slovakia and Germany.

What does that mean?

Comment: Meaning 4 here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strong, meaning 18 here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong, meaning 4 here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1000-strong battalion indicates the ***strength of the battalion in numbers***, or ***the number of fighters in the battalion***. The commander means to say that in his battalion of 1000 people, there are fighters from Bulgaria, Slovakia and Germany.

Look up this meaning of "strong" from [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong):

> ***Strong***
>
> 7.a. (postpositive) containing or having a specified number: *a navy 40 000 strong*.
>   b.(in combination): *a 40 000-strong navy*.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is 1000 (men) strong battalion. The "men" is understood.

Comment: That's not correct. "1000 men strong battalion" doesn't make sense; "1000-strong battalion" does. If you want to include 'men', it has to be something like "battalion of 1000 men". Alternatively, "1000 man battalion" - but *not* 'men', or 'strong' in this case.

Comment: @OllieFord: I put the "men" in parentheses and said that this was "understood."

Comment: Yes, you did. And I'm saying that it isn't "understood", because doing so makes it not make sense.

Comment: @OllieFord *1000 men strong* is a common idiom; you may find many contemporary examples from this [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22thousand+men+strong%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099), few of which are false hits.

Comment: @StoneyB Okay, first of all, [it's not even close](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thousand+men+strong%2Cthousand+strong%2C+thousand+man+strong&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthousand%20men%20strong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthousand%20strong%3B%2Cc0). Second, that's a different construct. In OP's quote, the sentence wouldn't make sense with 'men' - if you look at your books, they all phrase it differently, "should be 1000 men strong".

Comment: @OllieFord I think we're talking at cross-purposes. Neither I nor Tom Au suggests that *men* has been deleted or ellipted from the idiom, merely that it is the implicit unit of measure. And I point out that we do find the unit included in many instances. As you say, these instances occur in predicatives (and I would add in postpositives and supplements).